# Searching for string in text file, but getting multiple results

Tags: powershell, select-string

I'm trying to search for 172.21.134.16 specifically, but I get unwanted rows of others found (ie 172.21.134.161, 162, 163, etc. I just like the results to be 172.21.134.16.

```
PS C:\Scripts\Ping> Get-ChildItem -path c:\scripts\ping\hostnames.txt -Recurse | select-string -Pattern    '172.21.134.16'

hostnames.txt:119:SMFTBCR0601   172.21.134.16
hostnames.txt:120:SMFTBGT1101   172.21.134.161
hostnames.txt:121:SMFTBGT1102   172.21.134.162
hostnames.txt:122:SMFTBGT1103   172.21.134.163
hostnames.txt:123:SMFTBGT1201   172.21.134.165
hostnames.txt:124:SMFTBGT1202   172.21.134.166
hostnames.txt:125:SMFTBGT1203   172.21.134.167

PS C:\Scripts\Ping> Get-ChildItem -path c:\scripts\ping\hostnames.txt -Recurse | select-string -Pattern   '172.21.134.16'
```

expecting:

SMFTBCR0601   172.21.134.16

Answer (score 2):

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) has provided the solution in a comment - `-Pattern '\b172\.21\.134\.16\b'` - but let me provide background information:

- Generally, [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) looks for the `-Pattern` argument(s) as *substring(s)* on the individual lines of the files provided as
  [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instance via the pipeline, such as via [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) - the same applies to targeting files via `Select-String`'s own `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` parameters.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - As such, even if `172.21.134.16` were searched for *verbatim*, using `-SimpleMatch` (see below), it would invariably also match lines that contain `… 172.21.134.161 …`, for instance, or  `… 0172.21.134.161 …`
- [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) interprets its `-Pattern` argument(s) as [regexes (regular expressions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) by default.

  - If you want to search by *verbatim* (literal) substring, add the `-SimpleMatch` switch.
- If you want to *conditionally*  match substrings, depending on *what characters surround them*, using a regex - i.e. *not* using `-SimpleMatch` - is a *must*, such as in this case:

  - In a regex, `\b` is a *word-boundary assertion* that ensures that a character / subexpression that follows or precedes it only matches if the immediately preceding / following character isn't a *word* character (either a *letter*, a *digit*, or `_` (underscore))
  - However, if the substring you want to constrain this way is to be treated *verbatim* in the context of a regex, you need to be *escape* any regex *metacharacters* in it with `\`, notably `.` (which otherwise represents *any* character). To do so, you have two options:
  - In a *literal* pattern string, you can individually `\`-escape all regex metacharacters, which yields Santiago's solution:

    ```
     -Pattern '\b172\.21\.134\.16\b'
    ```
  - If you don't know the verbatim substring ahead of time or don't want to think about which metacharacters you need to escape, use the [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape) .NET method:

    ```
     -Pattern ('\b' + [regex]::Escape('172.21.134.16') + '\b')
    ```

---

<sup>[1] It also applies if you provide a file's lines one by one via the pipeline using the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet (without the `-Raw` switch), but this approach to providing input from a file is best avoided for *performance reasons*.</sup>